# Round down a number to its closest multiple of 3 using bash commands

Tags: bash

I have to round a number to its nearest least multiple of 3

For example:

```
For example:

n = 2939 => closest multiple of 3 is 2937
n = 3001 => closest multiple of 3 is 3000
```

Please suggest any commands to solve this.

I wonder if 'floor' command don't work in linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bash` can only handle integers, which makes it easier here. Divide the number by 3 and multiply it by 3.

```
n=2939; x=$((n/3*3)); echo $x
n=3001; x=$((n/3*3)); echo $x
```

Output:

```
2937
3000
```